# Best way to implement a formula

Tags: apex, custom-field, formula-field, operators

I have a scenerio which is based on a field of a record. This field is a lookup relation ship to another record. Example on my `abc__c` object I have
lookup to `xyz__c` object. The `xyz__c` object has a field named `type__c`. My formula is based on `xyz__c and type__c` values. The condition is:

1. If `xyz__c` is not blank
2. `type__C` has one of these `values -> 'CAR' , 'TRAIN' , 'BIKE' or 'PLANE'`
   If the above 2 condition satisfies then formula field should have 'FALSE' else it should have 'TRUE' text. Formula is a text type field.

This is what I got started with:

```
    IF( 
    OR ( ISBLANK(xyz__c), 
    (
    UPPER(xyz__r.type__c) != 'CAR' ||
    UPPER(xyz__r.type__c) != 'TRAIN' || 
    UPPER(xyz__r.type__c) != 'BIKE' || 
    UPPER(xyz__r.type__c) != 'PLANE'
    )
) 
    , 
    'TRUE','FALSE' 
    )
```

What I am know that I should be doing is putting all the combination of `type__c` in the formula field, meaning there could be case when the field has 'PLANE'
instead of 'CAR' so I might have to cover all those cases in the formula field. Is that correct? Is there a better way to implement this formula field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula will be as follows:

```
IF( 
    NOT(ISBLANK(xyz__c)) 
    && UPPER(xyz__r.type__c) != 'CAR' 
    && UPPER(xyz__r.type__c) != 'TRAIN'  
    && UPPER(xyz__r.type__c) != 'BIKE' 
    && UPPER(xyz__r.type__c) != 'PLANE', 
'TRUE','FALSE' 
)
```

Comment: Thank you. There is just one condition in this that I missed. If xyz__c is blank then it should return 'TRUE'. Meaning there is no need to check the type__c field if xyz__c field values is not present.

Comment: You can add it accordingly

Comment: Quick question - Do you think I should be using UPPER here? Is it case sensitive here?

Comment: UPPER is good for text comparison, if you are allowing user to enter the values

Comment: ok , i though in sales force string comparison is case sensitive. In apex would it means the same? Correct me if I am wrong pls.

Comment: It is case sensitive, so xyz__r.type__c == "CAR' is not same as xyz__r.type__c == 'Car'

Comment: In apex we use String.equalsIgnoreCase() method for case insensitive purpose